# Name of the service/cli tool that forwards a local port to a temporary/generated domain

Tags: web-services, server, localhost, command-line-interface, platform

I have used a service in the past that allows me to just run a command like `service 3000`, which sets up port forwarding and allows me internet access to my local server. They offered one running for free.

I can't for the life of me remember the platform/product/service that does this -- does anyone know its name?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ngrok** or **localtunnel** are both really good services!